# Using double offset in QGIS Expression String Builder?

Tags: qgis, function

I need to dynamically translate points 20 metres from their original point to a suitable cartographic position. I have a rotation value stored in a rotation attribute.

I cannot use this tool right because I cannot give values when using the function `cos ("rotation") * 20 or sin ("rotation") * 20`

Only number inside `'` (single quotation marks) are accepted. How I can use function inside double offset definition?

[image]

Sorry about Finnish interface!

[image]

Comment: If you add a textfield to the feature containing something like `20,50` the offset works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transform each number into string representations, and combine those with a comma. Based on your screenshot above, the proper expression would be:

```
to_string(cos("rotation")*20) || ',' || to_string(sin("rotation")*20)
```

Comment: yes, exactly! Thanks very much! =)